# How to use Drools Query and Inheritance in Query

Tags: java, drools

I have different configuration facts in the working memory. I need to use drools query to filter out all the fact that is relevant to a particular line item.

EDIT:

What I am trying to do is pass a class object inside the main query;

```
class Cart
{
 private List<A> aList;
private List<B> bList;
private List<C> cList;

//getter and setter
}
```

//Query

```
query "base" (Cart cart)
     Cart($lstA : aList, $lstB : bList, $lstC : cList)      from cart
     A( $code : code, $codeValue : codeValue)  from $lstA
     base1($code, $lstB )
     base2($codeValue, $lstC )
end

query "base1" (String code, List<B> $lstB)
         $lstB := ArrayList() from collect ( B( code == code))    
end

query "base2" (String codeValue, List<C> $lstC)
     $lstC := ArrayList() from collect ( C( codeValue == codeValue))
end
```

1. Main Class is Cart.
2. First query is taking parameter of Cart class object.
3. First attribute "aList" is field with list of A class object; A is consist of code and codeValue.
4. on the basis of code and codeValue calling the query base1 and query base2 inside the query A.
5. **I am also sending bList and cList is empty list. I want the value should be initialized from the query result of base1 and base2.**

Thanks

Comment: You aren't new on this site - so you ought to know that providing some code showing what you are trying to achieve is essential for concise and speedy answers. And: what do you mean by "inheritance"? Class/object inheritance of fact types?

Comment: @laune sorry laune for that. Like in rule, I can extend one rule to another rule. Could it be possible in case of query too.

Comment: There is no "extend" for query, but you can call a query from within another query, so this should give you about the same functionality. And you can call a query from a rule (but of course not vice versa).

Comment: @laune thanks laune for your clarification. I had also the same impression about inheritance as you have and even i tried but no luck. I updated the question. Please check. Thanks

Comment: @laune I did not get success in my efforts as I mentioned above. Could You please check where I am missing???

Comment: This doesn't look like any Drools query I've seen working. - If `$lstA` is bound to a `java.util.List`, what is `$listA.code` supposed to be? And the recursive query calls `B()` and `C()` won't work either. - Perhaps you can describe your problem rather than post some unlikely code.